# REST Server in TCL

Tags: rest, tcl

I would like to add a REST interface to an existing TCL codebase (so that the programms in other language can use the existing TCL code).

I found a [list of Webserver with TCL support](http://wiki.tcl.tk/602) but I have no idea which one would be a good solution to quickly map our TCL functions to HTTP/REST calls without tons of boilerplate code.

Has anyone here already done something like this and can tell me which of these servers would be a good (or bad/difficult) solution? 
Is there maybe another server/framework that is even better for this use case?

Comment: There's inevitably quite a lot of boilerplate in setting up an app-server; if nothing else, you've got to talk HTTP and map the verbs/resource paths.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Naviserver. Tcl is its embedded interpreter language. It has a low profile memory overhead, and is regularly maintained and tested for performance and low latency.

Answer (score 1):

For what you’re describing, you might consider [Wapp](https://wapp.tcl.tk/index.html/doc/trunk/README.md). It’ll do exactly the boilerplate elimination you want, and it’s easy to dive into. You’d probably want to use it as a library, rather than an app, given that you’ve got an existing codebase, but its operation past the initial setup is the same for that use case.